# Javascript, Video and Canvas on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, canvas

I'm usually developing in Java and JavaFX but now for the first I have a larger project in JavaScript - and found my first problems.

I'm trying to show a video in a HTML5-page using JavaScript. Just for testing I reduced the code to the following:

```
<body>
    <h2> Test </h2>
    <input type="button" id="forvidpl2" onclick="viplay( 'b016.mp4' )" value="Start Video">
    <input type="button" id="forvidpl3" onclick="viplayStop()" value="Stop Video">
    <script>
        var video_player    = document.createElement( "video" );
        var canvas_player   = document.createElement( "canvas" );
        var context_player;

        function viplayStop( vidsrc ){              
            video_player.pause();
        }

        function viplay( vidsrc ){              
            video_player.src = vidsrc;
            video_player.play();
            canvas_player.width = 600;
            canvas_player.height = 400;
            context_player  = canvas_player.getContext( "2d" );
            document.body.appendChild( canvas_player );
            viredraw();
        }

        function viredraw(){
            context_player.drawImage( video_player, 0, 0, 600, 400 );
            window.setTimeout( function(){ viredraw() }, 10 );
        }
    </script>       

</body>
```

I tested it on several environments and saw different behaviours:

- in Firefox on Windows the video was shown (with sound)
- in Firefox on Android (Android7 on Samsung A3 and Android 4 on Asus Tablet) the video is not schown but the sound is playing (so the video itself should be playing but the redraw does not work)

That's a bit annoying.
Is there anything wrong in my syntax (even if it seems to be standard).
Or are there any special Android-workarounds to be considered?

Thanks so far,
Peter

Comment: why do you copy the video content to a canvas and display the canvas? cant you simply show the video element? that makes no sense to me.

Comment: You are right if it was only showing the video. But as I said it's a larger project and it's not only showing the video itself but also some more image processing etc. in the back. So what is needed is to get the image/frame of the video to handle that - and that seems what's not working on some environments.